# Chronological listing of tables in MySQL database

Tags: mysql

While using phpMyAdmin I noticed suddenly that the table I frequently used had shifted to a different page, it used to be on page 2 where now it is on page 3. I'm the only one working on this database and find this quite peculiar.

There are quite a number of tables in this database so one or two new ones aren't going to stand out to me.

Is there somehow I can list the tables in this database in chronological order of being added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (and my) first inclination might be to use `SHOW TABLES`, but alas there does not appear to be a way to do an `ORDER BY`, q.v. the [official MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html).  However, you can query `information_schema.tables` and order by the `update_time`:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'
ORDER BY update_time DESC;
```

The above query will give you all tables in the `db_name` database sorted with the *most recent* first.